# Featured Image always shows up in custom post template

Tags: wordpress, templates, post

I am writing a custom post template. The featured image always show up big, occupying a all the page.

```
<?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                // get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
                the_post_thumbnail();

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

                the_post_navigation(
                    array(
                        'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous Post', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="nav-subtitle">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span> <span class="nav-title"><span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '</span>%title</span>',
                        'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next Post', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="nav-subtitle">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span> <span class="nav-title">%title<span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ) . '</span></span>',
                    )
                );

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>
```

I want to control the display of the featured image. Even if I remove the the_post_thumbnail(), a large image is shown.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default WordPress is providing some parameter you can use that.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

Comment: Even if I remove the_post_thumbnail() function, a large featured image is shown.

Comment: provide full code of that file and check the header that it is having any code with thumbnail?

Comment: I am using twentyseventeen theme.

Comment: I checked the header. Yeah it contains the thumbnail code.
`if ( ( is_single() || ( is_page() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id() ) ) :
  echo '<div class="single-featured-image-header">';
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id(), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );
  echo '</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->';
 endif;`

How do I fix it without changing the header file because the header file is being used for other post types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the size in get_the_post_thumbnail() as i replaced twentyseventeen-featured-image with thumbnail or you can add it via array

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id(), array(150,150); );
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id(), 'thumbnail' );

if ( ( is_single() || ( is_page() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id() ) ) : 
    echo '<div class="single-featured-image-header">'; 
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id(), 'thumbnail' ); 
    echo '</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->'; 
endif;
```

surely this will work.